# Is there a way to merge these two tables on SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to merge these tables into one? The idea is that the query identifies the ones that already exist on the second table and then update those rows on the final table.

I know very basic SQL, left join doesn't resolve the issue, union makes it more complicated and I got very confused using "EXISTS", also I'm not sure if I should use as a joining condition a varchar.

The desired result would be something like:

| Total | Section | EsConCita | EsAnticipada | EsAtrasada |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Enero | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 42 | Febrero | 42 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | Marzo | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | Abril | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 17 | Mayo | 12 | 3 | 2 |
| 12 | Junio | 12 | 0 | 0 |

```
DECLARE @Base TABLE (
        Total INT
        ,Section VARCHAR(20)
        ,EsConCita TINYINT
        ,EsAnticipada TINYINT
        ,EsAtrasada TINYINT
        )

INSERT INTO @Base
values ( 0, 'Enero', 0, 0, 0),
( 0, 'Febrero', 0, 0, 0),
( 0, 'Marzo', 0, 0, 0),
( 0, 'Abril', 0, 0, 0),
( 0, 'Mayo', 0, 0, 0),
( 0, 'Junio', 0, 0, 0)

DECLARE @aux TABLE (
        Total INT
        ,Section VARCHAR(20)
        ,EsConCita TINYINT
        ,EsAnticipada TINYINT
        ,EsAtrasada TINYINT
        )

INSERT INTO @aux
values 
( 42, 'Febrero', 42, 0, 0),
( 17, 'Mayo', 12, 3, 2),
( 12, 'Junio', 12, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Joining on month name (section)? Copy data from aux to base? Only existing rows, not inserting new ones that exist in aux but not base? And finally are you really using such an ancient version of sql server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want `left join` and then to take the value from `@aux` if it exists:

```
select coalesce(nullif(a.total, 0), b.total, 0), b.section,
       coalesce(nullif(a.EsConCita, 0), b.EsConCita, 0) as EsConCita,
       coalesce(nullif(a.EsAnticipada, 0), b.EsAnticipada, 0) as EsAnticipada,
       coalesce(nullif(a.EsAtrasada, 0), b.EsAtrasada, 0) as EsAtrasada
from @base b full join
     @aux a
     on b.section = a.section
```

Answer (score 0):

The query I think you need is a simple `join`

```
update b set 
    b.Total=a.total,
    b.EsConCita=a.EsConCita,
    b.EsAnticipada=a.EsAnticipada,
    b.EsAtrasada=a.EsAtrasada
from @base b join @aux a on a.Section=b.Section
```